# Getting images from assetsLibrary- full resolution

Tags: objective-c

I have an album of images, where i take from the iphone library all images as thumbnails ,and present an album .

When the user choose something from the album, i have to take the ORIGINAL image( not thumbnail) and save it .

So if i run on the assets, and save **only thumbnail** it takes 4 seconds(1000 images) but if i am trying to save the original size to array(so i can use it later) it takes forever and crash.

```
[group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:set options:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
 {
      CGImageRef imageRef = result.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage;
      UIImage *toSend=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];//original
      UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]];
      [assets addObject:thumbnail]; //works good
      [imagesToSend addObject:toSend]; // takes forever !
```

So, i need a solution so i can show the thumbnail, but also have some connection/pointers to the full resolution images and so it will not take forever to save them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was just to use 2 function . the first one is this, just to get the thumbnails, because its not takes time, and the user can see right away his album .

Later on when he choose his favorite image, i use this function again but in a full resolution and take just the relevant image needed , with :

```
range=NSMakeRange('image tag number you want' ,1);
NSIndexSet *set = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];


[group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:set options:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
     {
                     if (result != nil)
                     {

                      CGImageRef imageRef = result.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage;
                      UIImage *toSend=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```